# Perl-Rest::Client and credentials

Tags: rest, perl, credentials

Got an application where credentials don't work on curl with the -u option, I've to pass them with the -d option like that :

```
curl -v -k -X 'POST' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ "auth_info":{ "username":"myuser", "password":"mypwd" } }' 'https://.../rest/v1.0/auth'
```

With the rest::client in Perl, I can send credentials using the session headers, but it works only when application accepts the -u parameter of curl.

So I'm trying to have the solution to identify myself against this application with the rest::client

Tried with :

```
    %CONTENT_JSON = ( 
        'auth_info' => (
        'username' => 'myuser',
         'password' => 'mypwd')
    );
    $CONTENT_JSON = encode_json(\%CONTENT_JSON);
```

But I've the following error message on return of the query :

```
$VAR1 = {
          'service_status' => {
                                'details' => 'JSON request struct field is empty or invalid.',
                                'code' => 5437
                              }
        };
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Don't understand. How to create an named array with [] instead of {} like used for hash arrays ?

Comment: With <code> %CONTENT_JSON = ( auth_info => ['username','myuser'],['password','mypwd']) </code> I get "'JSON request struct field is empty or invalid.'"

Comment: `'auth_info' => (  'username' => 'myuser', 'password' => 'mypwd')` : You probably need to use a hash reference instead of a plain list. So replace `(` with `{` like this: `%CONTENT_JSON = ( 'auth_info' => {  'username' => 'myuser', 'password' => 'mypwd'});`

Comment: great, it works, I was so close in my first response about the curly brackets against the square brackets... But syntax problem !